# Making a multidimensional list from a one dimensional list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know the title is a bit confusing but I couldn't think of a better way of describing it. This is python code.

Say I have a list `a=["blue","yellow", "red", "green"]`. How would I split it so it looks like this: `a=[["blue","yellow"],["red","green"]]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make appropriate [slices](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) and put them in a list of their own:

```
a = [a[:2], a[2:]]
```

If you don't know the length of the list beforehand, you can use a comprehension:

```
chunksize = 2
a = [a[i:i+chunksize] for i in range(0, len(a), chunksize)]
```